# Problema al crear un ViewModelProviders

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

### Problema al crear un ViewModelProviders en Android Studio con Kotlin

En la versión de Android Studio 4.1.1 al intentar crear un ViewModelProviders junto un .of me sale tachado. He intentado de todo pero no se solucionarlo, y lo único que me sale es la opción ViewModelProvider pero sin "s".

```
class MenuPrincipalActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var adapter: MainAdapter
private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewModelProviders.of()` fue deprecado hace ya más de un año. En su lugar puedes crearlo  así:

```
private val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

o simplente así:

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
```